# Как сократить "дополнительные окна": "доп. окна" или "допокна"?

Tags: сокращения

Как пишется сокращение для дополнительных окон: доп. окна или допокна?

Answer (score 1):

**Правильно: доп. окна (это сокращение).**

Нельзя писать "допокна", так как это сложносокращенное слово, которое должно быть в словаре (а его там нет), например: **оргвыводы.**

**ОРГВЫВОДЫ,** -ов; мн. Организационные выводы — конкретные меры, принимаемые для реализации какого-л. решения. Сделать о.

Пример: Особенности **доп. соглашения.**

[**Сокращения (gramota.ru)**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD&start=495)